# Random walk with martingale solution

Tags: probability, martingales, random-walk

I am looking for a solution based on martingales. I only saw solutions based on MC with barriers and Gambler's ruin with $p=0.5$

A symmetric random walk, i.e. with equal probability one makes a unit step left and right, respectively. Given positive integers $x,y$ we position walker at place $x.$ What is the probability to reach $x+y$ before we reach 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability of reaching $x+y$ (rather than reaching $0$).  So the probability of reaching $0$ is $1-p$ (note that the probability of never reaching either end is $0$).

Let $Z$ be the position at the end of the walk.  We have $E[Z]=p\cdot (x+y)+(1-p)\cdot 0 = p\cdot (x+y)$.

But also, since it is a symmetric random walk, at each step, the expected displacement is $0$ (that is $\frac12 \cdot 1 + \frac12 \cdot(-1)$).  So the walker's expected ending position is $E[Z]=x$, the starting position.

Equating these two expression for $E[Z]$, we get $p\cdot (x+y)=x$.  So $p=\frac{x}{x+y}$.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. That's indeed a brief solution! Does anybody know how to apply martingales as alternative approach?

Comment: I would say that my solution does use the martingale property: the expected next position is equal to the current position.

Comment: @paw88789 Hey paw. I have a question regarding your previous comment. I've seen the Martingale property written as $E[Z_{n+1}|Z_{n},Z_{n-1},\ldots,Z_0] = Z_n$. Is this equivalent to writing $E[Z_{n+1}] = \cdots E[Z_0]$?